# Session storage in Symfony with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, session, caching

I started to work in a Symfony project and we use mongodb for session storage. In the code there are not call to save session, but in production we have a mongodb database of 150MB which in my opinion is so bigger. The problem is that expires query are really slow.

[image: Slow Query]

I have some questions:

- What kind of information is store in session database if in our code there are not calls to save any kind of information. Probably, is used by Symfony to store some internal info.
- My second question, if how to improve slow queries in order to no be stucked for session query.

Comment: Did you try recommendations shown on the screenshot? Looks like you have an index missing for "expires_at" field causing slowness.

Comment: I didn't try these recommendations because it is the default database created by Symfony and I don't know if I change the schema ould crash the app.